# Why am I getting an incorrect answer while trying to find the closest value in a BST given a target value?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

There is only one difference between the correct answer and my answer, and that is, I am traversing the entire tree instead of comparing the target with the node value and eliminating one-half of the tree in each recursion. Please help me with the explanation. Thanks.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
     public static int findClosestValueInBst(BST tree, int target) {
         //int closest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        // int val = 0;
         int vl = findClosestValueInBst1(tree, target, tree.value);
         return vl;
     }

  public static int findClosestValueInBst1(BST tree, int target, int val) {
    //  System.out.println((closest + "   " + Math.abs(tree.value - target)));
        //c = closest;
        if(( Math.abs(target - tree.value)) < ( Math.abs(target - val))){
            System.out.println(val);
            val = tree.value;
            
        }
    if(tree.left != null){
        return findClosestValueInBst1(tree.left, target, val);
    }
    if(tree.right != null){
        return findClosestValueInBst1(tree.right, target, val);
    }
    return val;
  }

  static class BST {
    public int value;
    public BST left;
    public BST right;

    public BST(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Question tree- Root =10,
Nodes-> [10,15,22,13,14,5,5,2,1],
Target: 12,
My output: 10,
Correct answer: 13,

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
     public static int findClosestValueInBst(BST tree, int target) {
         //int closest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        // int val = 0;
         int vl = findClosestValueInBst1(tree, target, tree.value);
         return vl;
     }

  public static int findClosestValueInBst1(BST tree, int target, int val) {
    //  System.out.println((closest + "   " + Math.abs(tree.value - target)));
        //c = closest;
        if(( Math.abs(target - tree.value)) < ( Math.abs(target - val))){
            System.out.println(val);
            val = tree.value;
            
        }
    if( target < tree.value && tree.left != null){
        return findClosestValueInBst1(tree.left, target, val);
    } else
            if(target > tree.value && tree.right != null){
        return findClosestValueInBst1(tree.right, target, val);
    } else
    return val;
  }

  static class BST {
    public int value;
    public BST left;
    public BST right;

    public BST(int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree looks like this:

```
     10
     /\
    5  15
   /   /\
  2   13 22
 /     \
1      14
```

Your code is not actually traversing the whole tree. This code:

```
if(tree.left != null){
    return findClosestValueInBst1(tree.left, target, val);
}
if(tree.right != null){
    return findClosestValueInBst1(tree.right, target, val);
}
return val;
```

checks the left subtree if it exists (and ignores the right subtree). Otherwise, check the right subtree if it exists. Otherwise stop the recursion. This is because once you reach a `return` statement, the entire method stops there, and the lines after that do not get executed.

So your code always prefers the left subtree without taking into account what number the node actually stores. So right off the bat, you went to the wrong direction - you are looking for 13, and the current node is 10, a closer value is gotta be bigger than 10, i.e. in the right subtree.

An implementation that actually traverses the whole tree would be something like:

```
public static int findClosestValueInBst(BST tree, int target) { // no need for the val argument!
    int leftClosest = tree.value;
    int rightClosest = tree.value;
    if(tree.left != null){
        leftClosest = findClosestValueInBst1(tree.left, target);
    }
    if(tree.right != null){
        rightClosest = findClosestValueInBst1(tree.right, target);
    }
    if (target - leftClosest < rightClosest - target) {
        return leftClosest;
    } else {
        return rightClosest;
    }
}
```

But why bother when you can do it more quickly? :)

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper. I also tried removing the 'return' keyword. And this time I can see in my output that the entire tree is getting traversed but still getting the incorrect output.

Comment: @user08 Removing the `return` won't help you. That's just ignoring the result of the recursive calls, which is something you shouldn't do. See my edit for a possible "traversing the whole tree" implementation.